# Player doesn't move when attempting to draw from a Player class

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop

So I'm currently in the process of refactoring my code in my game for the player and started a player class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Player
{
    protected String name;
    protected float health, maxHealth;
    protected Texture texture;
    protected int xPos, yPos;

    public Player(String name, float maxHealth, Texture texture) {
        this(name, maxHealth, texture, 0, 0);
    }

    public Player(String name, float maxHealth, Texture texture, int xPos, int yPos) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
        this.texture = texture;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }

    public Texture getTexture() {
        return this.texture;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return xPos;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return yPos;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(texture, xPos, yPos, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0,
                texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight(), false, false);
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        processMovement(delta);
    }

    public void processMovement(float delta) {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) {
            xPos -= 50 * delta;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) {
            xPos += 50 * delta;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using an orthographic camera, I haven't added any terrain yet as I'm going to do that next, however I want the player to always stay in the center but have the player move around the terrain when I draw it.

The code I have for creating the camera and drawing my player is as follows:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class GameState implements Screen
{
    private PixelGame parent;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Player player;
    private Texture playerTexture;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public GameState(PixelGame parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.playerTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("player/sprite.png"));
        this.player = new Player("Me", 20, playerTexture);
        this.spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        camera.update();
        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        player.draw(spriteBatch);
        player.update(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        float ratio = (float)width / (float)height;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(2f * ratio, 2f);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }
}
```

The player sprite doesn't seem to move, but when i change the values to something >75 the player sprite sprints across the screen like no-ones business.

Answer (score 2):

`xPos` and `yPos` in your class are ints. I would say that's the problem. Your `processMovement()` method is called like 100 times per second and `50 * delta` is most likely smaller than 1 so it's rounded to 0 because value has to be stored in int variable. Try changing `xPos` and `yPos` to floats.

And if that doesn't help (can't be sure without trying out the code) do some debugging. Put break points. See if `processMovement()` is called at all and if it is then what value variable delta has. How calculation goes.